# Magento 2 - Custom Module's _module.less file not updating

Tags: magento2, cache, frontend, less

In a custom module I've created I'm using a **_module.less** file in it.  At first it worked but any changes I make to it are not updating on the frontend.

I think it must be a cache issue but so far everything I've tried to fix it has not worked:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade; php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
php bin/magento cache:clean; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy;
rm -rf var/cache/; rm -rf var/generation/
```

I'm working in developer mode.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I checked [Less files in custom modules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111817/less-files-in-custom-modules) but unfortunately this does not answer my question.  It explains how to use LESS in a custom module but not how to troubleshoot the issue I am having with the cache other than what I've tried already (see above).

Comment: Make sure Path is correct & included correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Less files in custom modules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111817/less-files-in-custom-modules)

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/use-less-magento-2-template-modules/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ rm -rf var/cache/* var/full_page/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
```

This way Magento recompiles less files and also deploy all needed files again.

Comment: didn't work, I think it may behave slightly differently when you use _module.less

Comment: actually it worked after I ran  `rm -rf pub/static/ `,  so in total I ran `rm -rf var/cache/; rm -rf var/generation/; rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/; rm -rf pub/static/ ; chmod -R 777 .`

Comment: Please don't use 777! Magento2 doesn't need 777 als CHMOD nowhere. Highest is 755 for folders and 644 for files, depending on your webserver. But most likely errors won't appear if you use those.

Comment: I'm just using 777  on a dev enviroment Max, but good to point it out